# Element sliding down according to text when scaling browser

Tags: css, height

Ok, maybe a simple question.

I have got a div with text in it (p-element).

When i scale the browser the text gets less width to fit into. So it will add a new line of text. Fine by me, but this line of text overlaps the element beneath the text (in my case a footer). I want the footer to move down when the text adds a new line of text.

min-height with height 100% doesn't work...

Hope you understand my question, I'm Dutch so my English isn't very good.

EDIT: this is the page I'm talking about: http://stilld.nl/problem/

Comment: Do you have some code? Sounds like something is absolutely/fixed positioned, or floated, as new lines of text should normally cause elements below to be moved accordingly.

Comment: Everything is fixed relative. Clear: both doesn't work either. Something that might cause the problem: the footer is positioned with top: 50px;. Does that effect the problem?

Comment: Here is the page. I want the footer to move down, when browser scaled. http://stilld.nl/problem/

Comment: So...this is actually due to a number of problems. The main thing is that you use `position:absolute` on the `<p>` of your text content. If you change that to relative, or remove it entirely, the footer gets pushed down. But that'll result in the need for sweeping changes to your other styles to fix the rest of the page layout.

Comment: This actually works.... it's always in the details!.. Thank you so much. Post your solution as an answer and i'll upvote your answer:)

Comment: All right, I put it down as an answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's the comment I made:

The primary issue is that the `<p>` element of your text content has `position:absolute` applied to it. If you change that to `position:relative`, or even remove it entirely, the footer will get pushed down by the text content.

Unfortunately, this will change the rest of your page layout, so you'll need to make sweeping changes to the rest of your CSS to bring it back to its original state.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without looking at the code, but maybe if you'll add `clear: both;` to the footer style it will be sorted out.

Comment: This may be better suited as a comment, as it indicates a need for more information, rather than providing an actual solution.

Comment: Clear: both doesn't work either. Something that might cause the problem: the footer is positioned with top: 50px;. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: Oh boy, relative and absolute all together in the mix. The text is absolute and also the button beside it while the image is relative. First of all, place the image and the button together code-wise, since both of them are on the same side placing the text between them will just make things more complicated when scaling the page.